# Running NodeJS on all CPU cores in order to achieve maximum hardware potential

Tags: node.js, performance, express, pm2, multicore

**Hardware:**

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 virtual Machine on VMware Workstation with 4 core CPU and 6GB of RAM

**Issue:**

I've been searching for how to boost my NodeJS server and one of the solutions was to utilize all CPU cores of the processor which I'm doing right now.

So this is my entry file called server.js:

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.use("/", async (res, req) => {
  req.status(200).send('success');
});

app.listen(4300);
```

With help of `pm2` I'm spawning the maximum number of clusters `pm2 start server.js -i max` and I'm achieving this log:

[image]

With help of `autocannon` I'm targeting this server to kind of 'DDoS' to monitor how good it was to handle multiple concurrent requests.

Here is the code:

```
const cannon = require('autocannon')

const localHost = 'http://localhost:4300'

async function startMockUp() {
    let result = await cannon({
      url: localHost, // target url
      connections: 10000,   
      pipelining: 1,
      duration: 10 // seconds
    })

    console.log('request', result.requests)
}

startMockUp()
```

and here is the output for the first run:

[image]

**Now I'm trying to make the same thing but with only one cluster running:**

[image]

And getting this result:

[image]

So as you can see I'm not achieving x4 speed up running 4 concurrent clusters in addition to that single cluster was able to handle a bit more of requests.

Why is that happening?

Am I doing something wrong?

Is there a workaround to achieve better results?

Comment: Add some more tags related to performance to get proper attention. Remove `express` I think that is not useful.

Comment: What exactly would be better to provide?

Comment: I think these can help:  `node.js` `pm2` `multicore` `cpu-usage` `performance` anyway u cannot set more than 5.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using [cluster to fork off the processes](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html). This is the standard method to use multiple instances of node on a machine. My thought is that with the way you are starting the processes, only one of the instances is actually handling requests.

Comment: When I use "pm2 logs" it actually shows that every cluster is handling request